# AsyncTask - unchecked call to execute(Params...)

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I was looking for answer for hours but without result.

My app is using cameraCaptureSessions.setRepeatingRequest and saving/refreshing into TextureView privateTextureView.

**I want to take a picture from TextureView -> apply filter using AsyncTask -> save it to the ImageView. But getting warning** *"unchecked call to execute(Params...) as a member of the raw type AsyncTask"*

Application falls on button click(AsyncTask execute). Where am I wrong?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        .
        .
        .
        privateTextureView = (TextureView)findViewById(R.id.textureView);
        privateTextureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(textureListener);

        myTask = new ApplyFilterTask();

        privateBtnGetCapture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                pictureBitmap = privateTextureView.getBitmap();

                //Start MyTask
                myTask.execute(pictureBitmap);
            }
        });
    }

protected class ApplyFilterTask extends AsyncTask<Bitmap, Bitmap, Bitmap> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            int color = Color.parseColor("#ffa500");
            privateImageView.setColorFilter(color);
        }

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Bitmap... bitmaps) {
            Bitmap bmp = bitmaps[0];
            try {
                ImageFilters filter = new ImageFilters();
                bmp = filter.applyContrastEffect(bmp, 5);
                publishProgress(bmp);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //System.out.println("Error!!!! " + e);
            }
            return bmp;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Bitmap... bm) {
            System.out.println("TestProgress");
            privateImageView.setImageBitmap(bm[0]);
        }
        /*
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap... bm) {
            System.out.println("TestExecude");
            privateImageView.setImageBitmap(bm[0]);
        }*/
    }
```

Comment: `Application falls` does it **crash**? Or what do you mean under `fails`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The application failure mentioned by you seems to be due to multiple usages of the same `AsyncTask`. An `Asynctask` can be used only once. As mentioned in the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask) :

> The task can be executed only once (an exception will be thrown if a second execution is attempted.)

Your code creates a single `myTask` object that is used every time in the `OnClick` event listener. Instantiate a new `AsyncTask` everytime to avoid the application failures, as shown below.

```
    privateBtnGetCapture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            pictureBitmap = privateTextureView.getBitmap();
            AsyncTask<Bitmap, Bitmap, Bitmap> myTask = new ApplyFilterTask();
            //Start MyTask
            myTask.execute(pictureBitmap);
        }
    });
```

The warning mentioned by the IDE is however a separate issue that has to do with the declaration of `myTask`. You seem to have declared myTask as `AsyncTask` and not as `AsyncTask<Bitmap, Bitmap, Bitmap>` or `ApplyFilterTask`. Change the declaration and the warning would disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a unique instance of `ApplyFilterTask` for all your tasks, you can create new instance every time you click on `privateBtnGetCapture` and that can be done easily this way:

```java
 privateBtnGetCapture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                pictureBitmap = privateTextureView.getBitmap();

                //apply the filter this way
                new ApplyFilterTask().execute(pictureBitmap);
            }
        });
```